# Can't get value from cache_page table only cache_default

Tags: 8

I am fiddling a bit with drupal 8 cache. Looking at cache_page table and there is clearly a value with CID i am trying to fetch. I try this.

```
if ($item = \Drupal::cache()->get($cid)) {
  dsm($item);
}
```

and keep getting nothing for that CID, when I try some CID from cache_default. I get it without problem. So I am wondering how to get values from other tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide the cache bin `page`, otherwise it defaults to `default`:

```
\Drupal::cache('page')->get($cid)
```

Comment: Of course. :) It was late in the evening and I knew there must be something like that, but didn't find any parameters in get function.